# Tag synonym request: [prof-layton-last-specter] → [prof-layton-spectre-call]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The fourth game in the Professor Layton Series is called **Professor Layton and the Last Specter** in *North America*, and **Professor Layton and the Spectre's Call** in *Europe*. Due to this we currently have two tags for this game, and both are appropriate.

Therefore I think a tag synonym should be created for the following tags:

[prof-layton-last-specter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prof-layton-last-specter) and [prof-layton-spectre-call](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prof-layton-spectre-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!
<sup><sub>Better late than never</sub></sup>

I've actually expanded the main tag to [professor-layton-the-last-specter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professor-layton-the-last-specter) thanks to the [increased tag size limit](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/28182) from a few years ago. The end result:

[professor-layton-the-spectres-call](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professor-layton-the-spectres-call) → [professor-layton-the-last-specter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professor-layton-the-last-specter)

Comment: Thanks! It's a great thing we have hard working mods like you to pick up the slack of that lazy turtle.